# Jquery set interval problem

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I am making a facebook-like chat system so the users of my system can chat with eachother. For some reason, when I run this interval to check for new chats, it works fine in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. Is there anything specific about setInterval that Internet Explorer does not like?

**Edit:** The specific problem I am facing in IE, is that instead of loading up the new chats via this setInterval, nothing is happening at all. It works fine in firefox and loads the new chats as they are entered into the database. I am not sure which part of this code might be causing the error but I have a suspicion that it is the setInterval function.

Or could the be the frequency of Ajax requests?

```
  setInterval(function(){ 
      // Load Chats
     },500);
```

**On a side Note:**
On every interval I am having an ajax request load a PHP file that query's the database to see if there are any new chats added to the database since the page load. If it does then it sets up the new chat window for that chat session. Is it wrong to keep querying the database and running mulitpule ajax requests like that? Is there a better way?

**This is a simplified version of what I am doing:**

```
setInterval(function(){
   // Get new DB Entries 
   $.get(url, data,handlerFunction); 

   function handlerFunction(result){
   // Load new chats if they exist in the DB 
   } 
 },500);
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're facing in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything specific about setInterval that Internet Explorer does not like?

No, there isn't.

> Or could the be the frequency of Ajax requests?

Yes. Have the response handler set up the next request, don't send off another one every half second no matter how long they take to come back. You'll just hit the limit of simultaneous requests and queue up a long stack of them.

Comment: Do you mean set up the next request in the callback function?

Comment: Thank you!, How would I go about doing that? Because the callback function is the function handling the Ajax request?

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear, I edited the post to add the basic format of what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Chris B.: Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Also, you can name anonymous functions so that they can refer to themselves, eg.: `setTimeout(function blah() { ... setTimeout(blah, 500); }, 500);`

Comment: `function go () { $.get(url, data, callback); }; function callback(result) { …; go() }; go()` You can throw in a `setTimeout` if you want the next request to be sent off later then immediately after the previous one comes back.

Comment: Thanks, so I should remove the setInterval all together? Should i run the go function on document load then instead so it starts this loop kind of thing?

As for setTimeout that is just messing everything up for some reason.

Comment: I also don't want it to break if the request never comes back for some reason. Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: Yes, remove setInterval. Don't run onload, just start it wherever you are starting it now. If the request doesn't come back, then the error handler will fire, make sure that triggers the next request too.

Comment: David, don't I need to call the go function somehow though? This is running constantly while the document is open so thats why I had setInterval on it, there is no call to that function it just runs.

Comment: Yes. Just call it (as per the end of my example).

Comment: But the go function needs to be called initially for the callback function to run, thats what im asking about

Comment: Umm. Yes. As I said. You just call it initially. That is what `go()` does when it is outside of any function definition.

Comment: Sorry brother, didn't see it the first time. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can tell for now, that in cases as yours "ajax calls with timers" I avoid using setInterval and I use setTimeout instead.

Because for example `int=self.setInterval("clock()",1000);` This will call the clock function Immediately and will call it every one second regardless the excution time `clock()` may take inside.

On the other side, `var t=setTimeout("clock()",1000);` This will wait one second then will start calling the `clock()` function and if you called `settimeout` again it will wait till the `clock()` finish execution and will call it again.

Some useful links about this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful
http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm